# Get element attribute from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The objective is to create multiple sliders on the page by linking the slider to something. The slider must be activated by clicking or hovering the slider anchor. `sliderList` would be a array for making this process easier so i wouldn't have to link each other manually on the configs js file.

I need to get the attribute value from a element that is inside an array. In this case, **holder** is the array from where I want to extract the attribute value from the current array element. I tried doing this:

```
var holder = $('[slider-select]');

for (var i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
    var sliderList = $('[slider-target='
        +holder[i].attr('slider-select')
        +']');
}
```

It looks like **+holder[i].attr('slider-select')** isn't working. I'm learning JavaScript/Jquery and it's crazy how things goes wrong even when it makes all sense, lol. Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `sliderList`?

Comment: I have a few anchors targeting to a few sliders on the page. `sliderList` would be the array containing the targeted slider so i can make an easy connection without linking each slider to its anchor on the js file

Comment: explain what are you trying to do what you have done what you have tried and what is your problem so others can help .. thanks

Comment: @sam the objective here is to create multiple sliders on the page by linking the slider to something. the slider must be activated by clicking or hovering the slider anchor. `sliderList` would be a array for making this process easier so i wouldn't have to link each other manually on the configs js file.

Comment: @cslogic update your original post so everyone can read it not everyone read comments

Comment: @sam like so? sorry, i'm new to programming, even more to something like stackOverflow. but i promisse i'll get it quick!

Comment: I know that's why i am pointing you to what should do in every question you ask here

Answer (score 1):

`holder[i]` contains a plain DOM element, but you're trying to use the jQuery `attr` method on it.  You need to convert it into a jQuery object `$(holder[i])` (or else use the native `getAttribute` on the DOM element):

```js
var holder = $('[slider-select]');

for (var i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
  // Splitting this up a bit just to make it more readable:
  var val = $(holder[i]).attr('slider-select'); // instead of holder[i].attr(...)
  var sliderList = $('[slider-target="' + val + '"]');

  // confirm we got the element:
  console.log(sliderList.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div slider-select="A">A</div>
<div slider-select="B">B</div>
<div slider-select="C">C</div>

<div slider-target="A">a</div>
<div slider-target="B">b</div>
<div slider-target="C">c</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `attr` is a built-in function from jQuery, it's a shorthand of function `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

**In your case you want to do this:**

```
var holder = $('[slider-select]');

for (var i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
    var test = holder[i];
    var sliderList = $('[slider-target=' + holder[i].getAttribute('slider-select') + ']');
}                                                    ^
```

**A good approach is to use the jQuery built-in functions, so you can use this:**

```
$('[slider-select]').each(function() {
    var sliderList = $('[slider-target=' + $(this).attr('slider-select') + ']');                  
});                                                ^
```

## Resources

- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
- [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
- [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 0):

The attr method is not a function on the JS element object.  You'll want to wrap it in jquery to retrieve attribute values instead.  For instance

```
$(holder[i]).attr("slider-select")
```